How to efficiently make a lot of predictions with small neural network?
I need to make a lot of predictions with small neural networks (100-150 parameters). I implemented it in TensorFlow and faced efficiency problems. here is pseudocode:
for my_dense_netowrk,my_lstm_netowrk in networks_list
    my_dense_netowrk.paramters = 100
    my_lstm_netowrk.paramters = 150
    for images in data[:60]:
        @tf.function
        def tf_wrapper(images, state):
           model_data = meta_model(images)
           data_prepared = image_preparation(model_data)

           results = my_dense_netowrk(data_prepared)
           results.shape = (19000,1,1)
           
           better_results, state = my_lstm_netowrk(results, state)
           return better_results, state
           
        better_results, state = tf_wrapper(images, state)

my_dense_netowrk_n2.paramters = 100
my_lstm_netowrk_n2.paramters = 100

and continue...


I use tensorflow data pipeline api and actually all required data (data variable) can be allocated in my memory.
I didn't specify batch size for my neural network when building and insert data as a huge pile (batch size of 19000) to neural network to parallelize  everything. Even lstm is not bottled by sequence processing as it has to process 19000 inputs at a time. But when I increase my neural network parameters by a factor of 10(which I don't need) my code almost didn't noticed it thought batch size is pretty big.
@tf.fcuntion speed everything by a bit.
I tried profiling, but failed to find bottleneck as too many operations happens. I found out that kernel launch takes half of the time, because usually tensorflow expect this process to take a lot of time so its not optimized for such tasks I guess, because when I increase my loop from 60 to 6000 it becomes 10x more efficient on each single loop pass! Seems like it takes time for preparation.
image_preparation() function uses only tf ops like reshape, stack, tile, and I can not prepare data in advance.
I use macOS with M3 Max chip and there is no difference if I use GPU or CPU. I tried python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12.

So it seems that tensorflow is not bottled by my models, which is strange, and there is not much discussions on the internet about how to efficiently get many predictions from small models, everybody use such libraries for huge NNs. And gpu doesn't help at all though i think my pipeline should benefit from it as I use huge batches. So I really struggle to find a good solution to my problem and wanted to ask for an advise. Maybe there are better ml frameworks for my problem(PyTorch, Jax, maybe something else?) Or am I just bad at profiling? or should I try to build my own kernel in assembler for this? I don't know

You didn't describe the actual "efficiency problem", how much does it take currently to make predictions, and what is the target?
